# How to logout oauth2 client in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have the simplest oauth2 client:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class ClientApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {       
        return "Hello " + user.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name=application").run(args);
    }

}
```

I also have the following `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 9999
  servlet:
    context-path: /client
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

It is the full code. I don't have any additional source code. It works properly.

But now I want to add a logout feature. I've added an endpoint but it doesn't work. I tried to do the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request,response,authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        request.logout();
        request.getSession().invalidate();
    }
```

But I am still logged in and can access `/` url and it responds to me with the username.

Can you help me fix this issue?

### Update

I tried the approach described here https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Controller
public class ClientApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientApplication.class);

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String home(Principal user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws ServletException {
        model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());
        return "hello";
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name=application").run(args);
    }
}
```

and on FE I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT'
                    || settings.type == 'DELETE') {
                    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/
                            .test(settings.url))) {
                        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
                            Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        var logout = function () {
            $.post("/client/logout", function () {
                $("#user").html('');
                $(".unauthenticated").show();
                $(".authenticated").hide();
            });
            return true;
        };
        $(function() {
            $("#logoutButton").on("click", function () {
                logout();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and

```
<input type="button" id="logoutButton" value="Logout"/>
```

But it still doesn't work. It results in the following behavior:

Post `http://localhost:9999/client/logout` redirects to the `http://localhost:9999/client` but this page doesn't exist

**source code on gitub:**
client - https://github.com/gredwhite/logour_social-auth-client (use `localhost:9999/client/hello` url)
server - https://github.com/gredwhite/logout_social-auth-server

Comment: *`Post http://localhost:9999/client/logout` redirects to the `http://localhost:9999/client` but this page doesn't exist* What is the problem? Just add a page for `http://localhost:9999/client`. Or configure another page instead of `logoutSuccessUrl("/")`.

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the refresh token as well as access token from database to save space.

```
@PostMapping("/oauth/logout")
public ResponseEntity<String> revoke(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorization != null && authorization.contains("Bearer")) {
            String tokenValue = authorization.replace("Bearer", "").trim();

            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);

            //OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = tokenStore.readRefreshToken(tokenValue);
            OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
            tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid access token");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Access token invalidated successfully");
}
```

The URL to logout will be : **http://localhost:9999/oauth/logout**
Also, pass the access token in the Authorization header, as

Authorization:  Bearer 0cb72897-c4f7-4f01-aed9-2f3f79a75484

where, 0cb72897-c4f7-4f01-aed9-2f3f79a75484 is the access token.

Since, its Spring security, don't forget to bypass /oauth/logout url from authorize access, as

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/hello", "/oauth/logout");
}
```

Hope, it will solve your logout problem in Springboot2+Oauth2. Its working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Add following code snippet to your ClientApplication class. This will also clear your session details.

Replace below code with the configure method of your web security adapter class.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use the Spring Security built-in support for the /logout endpoint which will do the right thing (clear the session and invalidate the cookie). To configure the endpoint extend the existing configure() method in our WebSecurityConfigurer:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.antMatcher("/**")
     .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change Post to 
Get  http://localhost:9999/client/logout

it works for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to add logout url to your security configuration.

```
    .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .permitAll();
```